# packed chrome extension loses manifest on restart

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that is using the experimental sidebar API. It works beautifully when it is unpacked, but if I am running a packed version, and restart my browser, it no longer recognizes that I have asked for the sidebar in the manifest. I start getting these errors everywhere the sidebar is referenced:

```
Error during experimental.sidebar.getState: This extension has no sidebar specified.
```

This seems like it might be a bug in the sidebar API; or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the sidebar API is not documented anymore, code support for it has not been removed. If you are specifying your use of the sidebar as `"sidebar": {}` in your manifest file, you are most likely running into a [Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=86449) where object literals with empty values are removed when a packed extension is loaded at startup.

A workaround is to include a dummy key in the sidebar dictionary (e.g. use `sidebar": {"dummy": 1}` instead).

Comment: Note that the sidebar API is now being removed (http://codereview.chromium.org/9006027/), so by Chrome 18 it will not be available in experimental either.

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar API is no longer supported, not even as experimental. The code may still be available in some version of Chrome but the documentation is gone and the [feature proposal](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=51084) is going to be reworked.

Comment: Any idea what the last stable version that supports the sidebar was?

Comment: I don't. Keep in mind though that it was never officially support just available to experiment with.